# Want to run a function that is inside of a list

Tags: python

I want to run one of these functions when a certain strike is reached.

```py
draw_order = [draw_head(), draw_body(), draw_bothlegs(), draw_botharms()]

def strikecount(strikenum):

    global strikes
    strikes = strikes + 1

    if strikenum == 1:
        draw_order(strikes)

    if strikenum == 2:
        draw_order(strikes)

    if strikenum == 3:
        draw_order(strikes)

    if strikenum == 4:
        draw_order(strikes)
```

I tried using the indexes but was unsure on how to do it.

Comment: What's the point of the four conditionals if exactly the same happens in each one of them?

Comment: I wanted something different to happen in each of them, so I used indexes to try and get a different function

Comment: `draw_order = [draw_head(), draw_body(), draw_bothlegs(), draw_botharms()]` this is *not* creating a `list` with 4 functions. It's creating a `list` with the `return` value of 4 functions.  You most likely want to remove the parentheses `()` to assign the function objects themselves.

Comment: @gspr `draw_order` is a list which contains functions. OP needs to access a particular function in `draw_order` for each condition.

Comment: @gspr instead of putting an integer in the place, I created a strike variable that increases everytime I iterate the function.

Comment: To @gspr's point, calling `strikecount()` with parameters `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. produces the exact same result, so what is the point? At any rate, this feels like an XY Problem. Why have you taken such a convoluted path to calling these functions? What are you REALLY trying to solve by writing code like this?

Comment: @ChristopherChang Using a global like this probably isn't the best approach. Globals should generally be avoided. [See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/11044046). It'd probably be more effective to pass the value to the function or add it as an a attribute to an object.

Comment: I'm making a big assumption here, but this feels like maybe you want a "state machine". Iterating through a function and performing different actions based on the iteration (or other inputs). I think you just went a little to abstract with this list-of-functions approach. You are wading dangerously near `eval()` territory and that, to me at least, is a code smell.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips like starting with your own research. I found the linked questions by googling `python put functions in a list and call them later`.

Answer (score 0):

You can index them directly from the list and call them as follows. This is assuming that the draw functions are already defined.

```
draw_order = [draw_head, draw_body, draw_bothlegs, draw_botharms]

def strikecount(strikenum):

    global strikes
    strikes = strikes + 1

    draw_order[strikenum-1](strikes)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that indexing starts at 0, not 1. So whatever code passes in `strikenum` will need to be adjusted.